# Keras expects 2d array and a shape of (1,) simultaneously

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, keras

I load a model of keras by

```
model = keras.models.load_model('myModel.h5')
model.fit(x,y, batch_size=1, epochs=2)
```

Here at the last line it shows an error such that it wants y to be a 2D input. My y file's sample is
[0,0,-1]
which can be changed to [[0,0,-1]] or [[0],[0],[-1]] in 2Ds
In the first case,
Error: got array with shape(3,) where expected shape(1,) 
and in second case
Error: There are 3 samples where expected 1

Before this training part I run model.predict() during which it gives an output of format [[0.00251, -0.00526, 0.005476]]

What am I missing?

Model Definition

```
inputs = Input(shape=(32,32,1))
denseModel = DenseNet121(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(32,32,1), pooling='avg')(inputs)
denseModel = Dense(32, activation='relu')(denseModel)
denseModel = BatchNormalization()(denseModel)
denseModelPrediction = Dense(3, activation='tanh', name='predictions')(denseModel)

myModel = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=denseModelPrediction)
myModel.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
myModel.save('myModel.h5')
```

Merely initializing it here

Comment: Can we see your model definition (before you saved it)?

Comment: @jmsinusa I have edited the required model. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a classification network? The example y you give is [0, 0, -1]. Does this relate to three separate outputs that you are trying to get from the network, or are these three successive samples?

Comment: 3 separate outputs. But I want them to indicate some sort of probabilities. They aren't meant to classify and can be seen as independent. Predictions would be probabilistic between -1 and 1 but the true sample is -1, 0 or 1

Comment: So this is odd - I cant even define the network the way you did on the latest version of Keras. DenseNet is complaining about size of input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loss function (sparse_categorical_crossentropy) is expecting your y values to be one hot encoded. As you have three output nodes, the loss is expecting a y value with a (3,) shape, hence your first error.

If you are trying to regress three independent probabilities, I'd suggest switching your loss to something that compares the numbers (eg `loss='mse'` mean squared error). This should fix your input shape issue. You might also want to consider setting your outputs activation to sigmoid, so that it is forced to be between zero and one.

Comment: Thank you so much. jmsinusa. That parameter can also go the other way round like probability of going right on time 1, time 2 and time 3 so if I get -1 then it would go left. That's why I kept it tanh.